# Bash path variable, permission denied

Tags: c, bash, embedded, beagleboneblack

I can't create BASH variable `$path` couse I get the error permission denied.

I want to execute this BASH script in C code:

```
#define AINinit "\
#!/bin/bash \n\
path=`/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots` \n\
echo <password> | sudo -S echo cape-bone-iio > $path \n\
"
```

When I'm trying to execute `path=/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots` I'm getting permission denied error. The `/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots` is the directory.
I was trying to add `chmod 777` to `/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots` and it still doesn't works.

I'm executing this command in:

```
system(AINinit);
```

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: Is `/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots` a program you want to execute, or a file you want to `echo` a string into?

Comment: There's almost no C code in your question.  You need to show us what you're trying to do with this `AINinit` macro.

Comment: In my experience, trying to programmatically feed a password into `sudo` doesn't work well (not to mention the egregious security concerns of embedding the root password in your program like this).  A much better approach is to add specific commands allowed to be run (without password) by specific users to the [`sudoers`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) file using [`visudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/visudo).  (The only drawback is that the syntax of the `sudoers` file takes some learning.)

Comment: You want `path=/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots` (without the backquotes).  (Also, I'm worried about the wildcard `*` in there.  You can probably get it to work that way, but it'd be far better if you could explicitly specify the exact path.)

Comment: The exact path is `path=/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.[0-9]/slots`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you write the content of this macro to a file then call `system()` on that file, you have to use `chmod(filename, 0755);` before `system()` to make it executable.

(http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html)

---

Ouch, I just saw the edit in the question!
There is no chance that `system(AINinit);` could work as is.
`system()` requires a command line similar to what you would type in the terminal (not the content of a script file).

You need to use a file, as in the first part of this answer.

```
#define AINinit "\
#!/bin/bash \n\
path=`/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots` \n\
echo <password> | sudo -S echo cape-bone-iio > $path \n\
"
// convenient error checking omitted everywhere...
FILE *f=fopen("my_script", "w");
fputs(AINinit, f);
fclose(f);
chmod("my_script", 0755);
system("./my_script");
```

Alternatively you could change the macro so that you don't use a script file.

```
#define AINinit "\
echo <password> | sudo -S echo cape-bone-iio > `/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots`"
system(AINinit);
```

Note that, as mentioned in the comments, echoing the password is a dangerous solution (and which does not work well, for `ssh` it does not for example).

---

I think that the *permission problem* message does not come from the attempt to execute *some* code with `system()`.
I guess it is due to a bad usage of redirections with `sudo`.
`sudo a_command > a_file` performs the direction to `a_file` **before** executing `a_command` with some privileges.
A very common workaround is `a_command | sudo tee a_file` in which `a_command` is executed without privileges but `tee` opens `a_file` with privileges.
The inconvenient is that standard output of `a_command` is also echoed on the terminal.
The command `a_command | sudo dd of=a_file 2>/dev/null` should do the trick if the echoing is a problem.

All of this has nothing in common with the original question.

Comment: Okay I get it. But how can I achieve the `.*/` as this is number that I'm looking for in C. Couse filename should be without the bash code.

Comment: @Pukacza Just use the back-quotes on the same command line

Comment: The chmod `chmod(path, 0755);` doesn't resolve the permission problem. The `path` is okay and it's `/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots`.

Comment: @Pukacza what is `path` in your `chmod()` call?

Comment: `*path` is exactly what I want which is: `/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots` I checked that in debugger.

Comment: @Pukacza then the `chmod()` must not consider this path but the file in which you wrote your script. If you apply my second suggestion in the answer (one single command provided to the `system()` call), then `chmod()` is not necessary since this script file no longer exists.

Comment: @Pukacza I added some code in the answer to try to make it more clear.

Comment: Even the script and command line doesn't work. Still permission problem.

Comment: `sh: 1: /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots: Permission denied
sh: 1: cannot create : Directory nonexistent`

Comment: @Pukacza I added a third part in the answer.